Man tranforming into a tiger and killing people
I saw this movie when I was a kid, I can't remember it properly. A man tranforms into a tiger (it was definitely a tiger)  during nights and kills people.
More info: I don't exactly remember the language; May be English, otherwise it would be a Bollywood movie. I saw that movie around the year 2001 and I'm pretty sure the movie was from around the 90's. I remember a scene of the man by the pool.

Approximate year? Country\language? What did he look like? Any other plot details or particular scenes? And are you 100% sure it was a tiger and not some other animal?

definitely it was a tiger . i dont exactly remember the language may be english otherwise it would be a bollywood movie . i remember a scene of the man by the pool he will be killing people during the nights transforming intoa tiger

Added and I have a movie in mind, though it would really help if you tell us when were you a kid...

i saw that movie around the year 2001 and i'm pretty sure the movie was around the 90's...

Possibly the 1992 horror film Junoon from India about a man turning into a tiger:

Some villagers predict that on every full moon night a cursed man-eating tiger lingers about making any human beings in sight its prey. Disbelieving this, two hunters, Vicky and Arun, go about their hunting adventures only to be attacked by the tiger; while Arun succumbs to his wounds Vicky is gravely wounded and is subsequently admitted to the hospital and is under the care of a female doctor, Nita. Vicky falls in love with Nita and asks her parents for her hand in marriage to which they agree and their marriage is celebrated. After marriage Nita notices Vicky behaving in a strange manner but what she is unaware of is that Vicky is now a human shape-changing tiger who is ready to make anyone his meal - including her. 

He attacks a woman in a hotel pool at some point. Here's a transformation scene from the film:




thankyou i will look into that and i would be grateful if you name the top most latest horror and thriller movies , if possible the most grosing movies also..

Added a scene. As for the lists, you could always use IMDb's search engine and Box Office Data by Genre.

thank you that was the movie...and thanks for the information too..

@charanleo No problem, but don't forget to click on the check mark to mark the question as 'solved'.

It always bothers me why was it called horror rather then comedy ;D. Anyways though the same, +1

@charanleo you can Accept Walt's answer by ticking it if you like to do so. This is such a coincidence, my brother was asking me about this movie just yesterday and today i saw it here too. More of a cult movie i believe.

Another possibility, although they aren't lions, is the Malcom MacDowell movie Cat People, where "people who turn into panthers after mating and who must then kill in order to take human form again."
